# a quarter minutes ago

Tags: phrase-request, time

I was wondering is there a shorter way of saying '**a quarter minutes ago**', or '***half an hour ago***' in the following scenario:

> The elevator is not working now, but it was working *a quarter minutes ago*.

Could you suggest a shorter phrase to use instead?

Comment: How about 15 seconds ago, or 30 minutes ago?

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish thanks, it's a good alternative, but I don't think it is shorter too..

Comment: It's not hugely shorter but by one word... **a quarter minute ago** (which sounds weird) to me versus **15 minutes ago**. Same with **half an hour ago** versus **30 minutes ago** so yes, only shorter by one word even if you spell out the numbers but no huge difference for sure... just quick thought I had for your question.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish a word less is really better, but doesn't using '_15 minutes_' make it to sound more accurate than using '_a quarter_'?

Comment: Unless you need to be that precise, why not use *a minute ago*, *a second ago* or even *an instance ago*? Any problem using them?

Comment: "A quarter minutes ago" does not compute.  "A quarter minute ago" would be 15 seconds.  "A quarter hour ago" would be 15 minutes.  Except perhaps in certain stiffly formal situations (formal wedding invitations, eg) there is no reason you cannot use the "15 seconds" or "15 minutes" form (spelling out "fifteen" if you wish), if that is easier for you to understand/say.

Comment: (Perhaps it's not clear to you that "a quarter" means "one fourth" or "1/4" -- it does not mean "fifteen".  A US "quarter" coin, eg, is a quarter of a dollar or 25 cents.)

Comment: Other languages have expressions shorter than three words to describe the specific concepts "15 seconds ago" or "30 minutes ago"? Can you give examples? (I'm wondering whether you're looking for a *less* specific phrase - such as "just now".)

Comment: @HotLicks thank you. I didn't know that. I was trying to mean 15 minutes by a quarter minutes.

Comment: @MarkBannister "15 minutes ago" or "30 minutes ago". since I state 15 and 30, I feel like they has to be accurate. What I try to say is something about approximately 15 minutes ago and I already provided an example

Comment: @joker13: You have provided examples of what you are *trying* to say in English, using more than three words, in your question - I was asking for examples of *"much shorter synonyms in other languages"* (as in your comment to Rathony).

Comment: @MarkBannister in persian, you can say it in two words :)

Comment: What can be said in two words in Persian, "a quarter hour" or "a quarter hour ago"?

Comment: @TimRomano "a quarter hour ago".

Comment: So, one of the two Persian words means "a quarter hour" and the other means "ago"?

Comment: @TimRomano exactly :)

Comment: So, your question is, "What is the shortest way to say *a quarter hour ago* in English?"  When speaking elliptically, we can say "quarter" to mean "a quarter hour", but not when used with "ago"; we do this only when saying what time it is now.  "What time is it? --Quarter past" or "What time is it? -- Quarter to".

Comment: @TimRomano thank you. can we use it in the elevator example too? :D

Comment: No, it cannot be used with "ago", because *ago* does not refer to the time of day, but to a broader chronology (it could be weeks or years or decades or eons *ago*), whereas "past" and "to" in "(a) quarter past" and "(a) quarter to" refer to the hour of the day.

Comment: Now figure out what a "quarter horse" is!!

Comment: @HotLicks nice one xD cool

Comment: @Hot Licks: Or why military officers live in quarters, and some of them do their work in headquarters :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these comments you made:

- What I try to say is something about **approximately 15 minutes ago**
- doesn't using '15 minutes' make it to **sound more accurate** than using 'a quarter'?
- a word less is really better

#### It sounds like you are looking for a concise way to say an approximate time.

---

My answer is aimed at suggesting a short phrase that means *a short but unspecified amount of time*. (I'm not looking to give you a phrase that is exactly equivalent to 15 minutes, or 15 seconds, because I don't believe that's what you're after.)

With that in mind, I suggest the phrase *just now:*

> The elevator is not working, but it was working *just now*.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just-now) defines *just now* as: "a very short time ago." [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/just%20now) defines it as an adverbial phrase meaning: "only a moment ago." TFD defines it like this:

> **just now** a short time ago : *I came from a meeting just now where the governor said he would veto the proposed law*.

The phrase could be used to mean a few seconds ago, or a few minutes ago, depending on the situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer and also for the links. vocabulary.com is surprisingly helpful for practicing vocab.